# C# Serialisation into memcache

Tags: c#, serialization, memcached

I have the following basic C# console application method which writes a string into memcache. I am trying to find a way to ...

1) Serialise it (Not using XML)
2) put into memcache
3) De-serialize is (Not using XML)
4) Place into a string

```
 using (MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient())
        {
            client.FlushAll();
           // store the value
            client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "myObj", "testval");
            // retrieve the value
            string value = client.Get<string>("myObj");
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Does anyone have a basic example of how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Just convert the string to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

What MemcachedClient are you using? beitmemcached, EnyimMemcached... Both serialize objects to BinaryFormatter by default. If it is a string then theirs are using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes